# Runing and monitoring several instances of a custom C++/C# application automatically, possible?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, scheduled-tasks, multiple-instances

Ok, I guess I need to make myself a bit clearer, sorry.
I DO NOT have problem with the app it self. it runs single or multiple instances just fine. we have mechanism built in to prevent cross-instance interference, file/record blocking etc..

the issue is that sometimes  when running several instances, (some one go and click on myapp.exe several times manually ) one or more instances can crush. 
be it from a bad data in the file, loss db connection, what ever. I am still trying to figure out some of the unexplained crushes and hanged instances sources.

what I am looking for is a way for me to setup a monitoring process that 
A. can identify each instance of the app running  as separate entity. 
B. check if that one instance is running and not hanged / crushed , this maybe mediated but me changing the code and force the app to quit if a fatal error is detected, as in I crushed and can not recover I quit, kind of setup. 
C. start new additional instances up to the total count of desired instances running. that is I want to have a minimal count or app running at the same time. if current count is less start up new until desired count is reached.

what would be the best approach to have this setup.

---

I have a custom inhouse application written on C++ and C# mixed API. 
it is a file processing parser for EDI process, that takes data from flat files or Flat file representation from a DB table (we have other modules that store a contents of flat file in DB varchar field) and process and store data in appropriate DB tables. 
it works fine for the most part, but several clients have a need to run multiple instances of it to speed up the process.

problem is that when the app crashes, there is no automatic way I know  to identify the instance that crashed , shut it down and restart.

need help to identify my options here. 
how can I run the same EXE multiple time yet monitor and manage each in the event of instance misbehaving.

a code change is possible but C++ is not my main language so it will be a nightmare for me to do any extensive changes.

PS>  the app is a mix of C++ and C# modules with MSSQL DB backend

thanks.

the process is monitored with MSSQL SPs. an issue can be identified by luck of new records processed and other factors

my needs are to be able to 
1. start several instances of an app at the same time.
2. monitor each instance of running EXE and if crush is detected kill and restart that one instance.  I have a kill switch in the app that can shut it down gracefully, but need a way to monitor and restart it. but only that one.

Comment: You can try out and run multiple threads whilst managing them with condition variables/mutexes. Please take a look at this book I found online about C++ concurrency [C++ Concurrency
in Action](https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/files/CplusplusConcurrencyInAction_PracticalMultithreading.pdf).

Comment: if you started the process from your own c# app you can check if the app is still alive.

Comment: I do not start process. it is an executable file that is run manually.

Comment: In my setup I have each application write a record to a database table on startup, then update a timestamp on the record periodically. I have a central service that monitors the table, and looks for instances that haven't been updated within the defined period, it then deletes the record and then restarts the application. I believe Apache Zoo Keeper does this sort of thing at an enterprise scale.

Comment: yes we do the same thing. but some times the app just stop responding. I need a windows local solution.  the DB cleanup is automatic. when app starts it calls DB and gets a token. the user/app settings determined the life of the token and it gets clean up or expires fine.  but, if app crashes I need to restart it. nothing I tried so far works. I am still experimenting with windows task/schedule but no luck so far. it's like all instances look the same to it. so can not maintain a count.